# Display a new component with button click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im making my first react ptoject. Im new in JS, HTML, CSS and even web app programing.

What i try to do, is to display some infomration on button click.

I have an API, that looks like this:

```
endpoint: https://localhost:44344/api/Projects

My Data from it:
[{"id":1,"name":"Mini Jira","description":"Description for first project in list","tasks":null},{"id":2,"name":"Farm","description":"Description for second one","tasks":null}]
```

And im fine with that, i can get it easily by `axios` in my react app.

Now i will show you my `Project.js` Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ListGroupItem, Button, ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import ProjectDetails from "./ProjectDetails";

class Project extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ListGroupItem>{this.props.project.name}</ListGroupItem>
        <Button onClick={Here i want to display new component with details }bsStyle="primary">Details</Button>
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Project;
```

I have all data from api in `project` type.

My question is, how to display component that i named `ProjectDetails.js` on button click? I want to show all  data stored in `project` from my api in separate view (new page or somethig like that).

View looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for any advices!

**EDIT:**

based on @Axnyff answer, i edited `Project.js`. it works ok. But when i want to (for testing) displat `project.name`, i get error `map of undefined`. My `ProjectDetails.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ProjectDetails extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <li>{this.props.project.name}</li>;
  }
}

export default ProjectDetails;
```

**EDIT2:**

In `Project.js` in @Axnyff answet i just edited that line:

```
{this.state.showDetails && (
      <ProjectDetails project={this.props.project} />
    )}
```

i passed project by props, now it works like i want too. After click it displays `project.name` that i clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use state in your React component.
Let's create a field called showDetails in your state.

You can initialize it in your constructor with

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); // needed in javascript constructors
    this.state = {
        showDetails: false,
    };
}
```

Then you need to modify the onClick to set that state to true

```
    <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ showDetails : true })} bsStyle="primary">Details</Button>
```

And then use that state to show or not the ProjectDetails:

```
{ showDetails && <ProjectDetails /> }
```

The full component should look like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ListGroupItem, Button, ButtonToolbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import ProjectDetails from "./ProjectDetails";

class Project extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props); // needed in javascript constructors
      this.state = {
          showDetails: false,
      };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ListGroupItem>{this.props.project.name}</ListGroupItem>
        <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ showDetails : true })} bsStyle="primary">Details</Button>
        { this.state.showDetails && <ProjectDetails /> }
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Project;
```

You can then modify the logic to add a toggling effect etc.

If you haven't done it, you should probably follow the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: That looks pretty, easy, i will check it in seconds! But tell me, how `ProjectDetails` would now, that i want to display an item's detail that i clicked? For example from my post, when i clicked on Details in `Mini Jira`, how component `ProjectDetails` would know, that i want to display details from that record from my api?

Comment: If your ProjectDetails component, is relative to one project you probably need to pass it a props like `<ProjectDetails name="Mini Jira" />`

Comment: I will have a lot of projects, i want to display (for example) description based on which button i click. How to pass `project` to `ProjectDetails.js` then? Its the main thing i want to do, because your solution works pretty ok! (i can display something on button click, you answer works) but my second part of question was how to display details based on my `project`? Like you can see, for now i have 2 projects, `Farm` and `MiniJira`

Comment: Can't you pass this.props.project.name to your ProjectDetails object?

Comment: when i add in `ProjectDetails.js` that line in return (for testing only): `return <li>{this.props.project.name}</li>;` i get en error, that `project.name` is of undefined :/

Comment: Look into my edit. I edited Project.js to your form and it works pretty ok

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Bar() {
  return <h1>I will be shown on click!</h1>;
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { showComponent: false };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showComponent: !this.state.showComponent });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showComponent && <Bar />}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```